# Grabbing Article Meta Data (Meta Description, Meta Key) in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, metadata

I'm trying to add a meta description and meta key of an article to its RSS Feed for Joomla. I'm using the article custom meta description and meta key fields for storing stock ticker symbols and trying to put those into the RSS Feed component. Trying to solve this by grabbing the values for the meta data for each article. I was hoping there would be some kind of global variable that has all the content parameters stored in it, kind of like wordpress loop. But whether I'm looking in the wrong places or there aren't any information on the web for this matter.

I can make a call to the database and grab it but I didn't want to go through the hassle of filling in the security hole I might create. I'm fixing this minor issue for a very populated blog and I don't want to create a hole in their system.

So I was wondering if there are any method or a function I can use to get the variables from the content table? It doesn't have to be an exact answer to my problem, if someone could just point me in the right direction, that would really be nice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you somewhere in your code you loop your article objects through the db
You can try this piece of code:

```
$metakey=$articles->metakey;

$metadesc=$articles->metadesc;
```